# Why is error_log not being called during my cron?

Tags: wordpress, cron

I'm trying to schedule that runs every five minutes.

The code below successfully schedules the cron, and it shows up in WP Crontrol, but "Doing a cron!" never appears in the error log.

What's going wrong?

```
add_action('do_cron_stuff_event', 'do_cron_stuff', 10, 2);

function do_cron_stuff()
{
    error_log('Doing a cron!');
}

add_filter('cron_schedules', 'cron_stuff_add_5_minute_cron_interval');

function cron_stuff_add_5_minute_cron_interval($schedules)
{
    error_log("cron_stuff_add_5_minute_cron_interval called");

    $schedules['five_minutes'] =
    [
        'interval' => 300,
        'display'  => esc_html__('Every Five Minutes')
    ];

    return $schedules;
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'cron_stuff_plugin_activation');

function cron_stuff_plugin_activation()
{
    error_log("cron_stuff_plugin_activation called");

    if (wp_next_scheduled('do_cron_stuff_event') === false)
    {
        wp_schedule_event(time(), 'five_minutes', 'do_cron_stuff_event');
    }
}

register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'cron_stuff_plugin_deactivation');

function cron_stuff_plugin_deactivation()
{
    error_log("cron_stuff_plugin_deactivation called");

    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('do_cron_stuff_event');
}
```

Comment: do you see `cron_stuff_plugin_activation called` called in log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `error_log` actually *was* being called, but because it was activated by a system cron, the error log output was being sent to a different error log file than the usual one.

To fix it, I used the error_log function's [third parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) to send the output to a custom log file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you're specifying 2 `$accepted_args` for

```
add_action('do_cron_stuff_event', 'do_cron_stuff', 10, 2);
```

while `do_cron_stuff` accepts none.

Change it to

```
add_action('do_cron_stuff_event', 'do_cron_stuff', 10);
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. My problem turned out to be something different, but the argument count also needed to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> WP-Cron works by: on every page load, a list of scheduled tasks is checked to see what needs to be run. Any tasks scheduled to be run will be run during that page load. WP-Cron does not run constantly as the system cron does; it is only triggered on page load. Scheduling errors could occur if you schedule a task for 2:00PM and no page loads occur until 5:00PM.
>   https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

This means that you should trigger(query) /wp-cron.php from outside every 5 minutes.